# I have an annoying zoom on my screen - ubuntu20.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, screen, display-resolution

I have an annoying ZOOM on my laptop screen (ubuntu20.04)

I tried to purge the Intel video server and reboot but with no result.

```
$ sudo apt purge xserver-xorg-video-intel
$ reboot
```

On my **laptop Settings > Display > Resolution**, I have only *960×540* *(16:9)*, which is the actual zoom, and I have no idea how to get the usual one.

My **Windowing System** is *X11*.

Here is the lspci output:

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI KT (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev bb)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

Here is the xrandr output:

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 960 x 540, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 960x540+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 174mm
   960x540       59.82* 
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   480x270       59.82  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I think this was a result of fixing the unsupported GPU with my nvidia 720M. (I've already purged nvidia*, and have no output to show with nvidia-smi..)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Younes

Comment: I tried to add a new mode to my display resolutions modes, I succeed but still not a proper way to fix my issue. The display don't fit the full screen however it's less annoying than before.

I did that with the following commands:

    $ xrandr --newmode "MyMode" 111.00 1504 1592 1744 1984 900 903 913 934 -hsync +vsync
    $ xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "MyMode"

Then a new mode appears on the display window. *1504×900 (16:10)*

(I'm using a DELL-latitude-E5440..)

Younes

Comment: I tried to add the 1366×768 mode and it seems that the problem is solved, but in a hobby way. I wish to have a better answer, because I'm not sure with the arguments I've used on the xrandr --newmode line!
Thanks and best,
Younes